# Separate String from Integer(Separate Fontname from Font Size)

Tags: c#, string, fonts

I have this fontname property which returns fontname+SPACE+fontsize eg: `Sans 12` but for creating a font object i need the ***font name*** and **font size** separately.I hope fonts does not have a number in their names.

So im looking for a way to split this string to 2 parts.

Comment: Any chance you've checked if string have a method `Split` that allows "to split this string to 2 parts"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, i know but where to split,like a fontname can have spaces and im not sure if a fontname has a number

Comment: You really should clarify restrictions... If there is always space + size at the end basic `LastIndexOf` would do... But beware of font names like this - http://www.whatfontis.com/PR-Swirlies-10-pr-fonts.font :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah there are fonts like that.The fontsize is limited to a maximum of 3 characters.I can start from the end of the array and count back until a space is encountered.Does this approach have problems.

Comment: Manually implementing `LastIndexOf` is strange, but indeed an option... Anyway bit provided code for you already in the answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Okay... I did not look the method in detail.This is already implemented.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the property returns something like "Some Font2 With 5 Variants 24", you can do the following:

```
   //fontProperty="Some Font2 With 5 Variants 24"

   string fontNamePart=fontProperty.Substring(0,fontProperty.LastIndexOf(' '));
   int fontSize=int.Parse(fontProperty.Substring(fontProperty.LastIndexOf(' ')+1));
```

To make the size part "white-space-character-proof" so that it can safely be converted to an int you can additionally trim it before converting. Like this:

```
   int fontSize=int.Parse(fontProperty.Substring(fontProperty.LastIndexOf(' ')+1).Trim());// I know, looks a bit ugly
```

This should work on any kind of font provided the last part is always the size of the font.

Comment: Thanks,But the fontNamePart misses the last character.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it. It was a typo from my test application. Just need to remove -1 from the first line.

Comment: You can check this code in a Console Application.            `string fontProperty = "Some Font2 With 5 Variants 24";
            string fontPart = fontProperty.Substring(0, fontProperty.LastIndexOf(' '));
            int size = int.Parse(fontProperty.Substring(fontProperty.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",fontPart,size);
            Console.Read();`

Answer (score 3):

This should give you what you need:

```
var yourString = "SAN 1 12";
var lastSpace = yourString.LastIndexOf( ' ' );
var fontName = yourString.Substring( 0, lastSpace ); //gives SAN 1
var fontSize = yourString.Substring( lastSpace ).Trim(); //gives 12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but will this work with fonts like http://www.whatfontis.com/PR-Swirlies-10-pr-fonts.font as AlexeiLevenkov mentioned in the comments.Please see the comments above.The fontsize is limited to a maximum of 3 characters.I can start from the end of the array and count back until a space is encountered.Does this approach have problems.

Comment: With the font "PR Swirlies 10" and assumed size "99", yourString would be "PR Swirlies 10 99", and the code would still work.

Comment: Throws an error where you get the size."Index must refer to a position within the string"

Comment: I have not really tested the code, do you mind debugging it a little?